# Components in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, components

I want to set up data binding using a custom component.

Basically, I'd like to do something like this in my XAML file:

```
<ControllerDataBindingBridge>
    <Bind TargetControl="eFirstName" Property="FirstName"/>
</ControllerDataBiondingBridge>
```

How do I create ControllerDataBindingBridge, there doesn't appear to be a simple Component which isn't visible, only UIElements.

Is this supported at all? I see things like Storyboard, that inherits from DependencyObject, is this the base class I want?

Any webpages, tutorials, hints, or tips anyone can give me towards achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DependencyObject is the base class you want.

I'd start by having a look at the Expression Blend SDK (Behaviours and Triggers). See [here](http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/) for samples. The binding listener sample may prove useful.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed, already built a dummy class In can add in my resource section with a collection of sub-items, works nicely.